# Handling java.lang.NullPointerException ERROR

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Good day :)
I have this java codes and it is connected to SQL which add data (Name, Date) into my SQL table using textbox(txtname,txtdate)..The proble is that,this kind of error appears everytime I save the record `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException at cms.Add.jButton1ActionPerformed(Add.java:78)....` ..Any help will be appreciated.Thanks!

here is the code..

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

try{

    String sql = "Insert into login_tbl (Name,Date) values(?,?)"; 


        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, Txtname.getText());
        pst.setString(2, Txtdate.getText());

        pst.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Added");

        }
        catch(HeadlessException | SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        } 

    }
```

Comment: `conn`  might be null.

Comment: which line is line 78?

Comment: pst can't be null. Either the connection successfully returns a prepared statement, or it throws an exception.

Comment: JOptionPane is a class, not an object. It can't be null. conn is null. Telling why is impossible with only the posted code.

Comment: Trying to debug is the most elegant answer for all these type of problems

Comment: Maybe I just need to focus on debugging.. Thanks for the tips btw :)

Answer (score 0):

It means that whatever variable you have at `line 78` is null / not initialized.
Make sure that whatever value it is, it is not null, then run your program again.

Answer (score 0):

Check for null on the connection object. Also, you displaying the exception message in a dialog. That will be one long dialog. Why not log it or print it to stdout?

Comment: Why should the OP always check for null? He shouldn't. He should simply make sure to initialize the connection. If it's initialized, no need to check. And the statement will never, ever be null. Checking for null will just add useless boilerplate code.

Comment: Yes but from his error message, conn might be null. And you are right, statement can't be null. I'll edit that.

Comment: Let's say you check the connection for null. Why would you do if it's null? The best thing you can do is to signal the bug, by throwing a NullPointerException. And that's already what happens if you don't check for null.

Comment: Touche. I guess OP needs to spend sometime debugging (can the databse be reached? are the database properties valid? etc)

Comment: Maybe I just need to focus on debugging.. Thanks for the tips btw :)